# accessing react hooks functions and state in multiple components

Tags: reactjs

I have an app that uses react hooks. Currently I have all the state and functions in the main app function and 1 big render. I want to split this in to separate components, but still be able to access global state and functions from each of these components. What would be the best way to structure the code?

```
function App() {
  const [accounts,setAccounts] = useState([]);
  const [balance,setBalance] = useState(0.0);

   useEffect(() =>{
     setBalance(1000);
     loadMetamask();

    const exampleFunction = () => {
      console.log("TEST");
    }
  });

 render(
    <div className="App">
      <Component1 />
      <Component2 />
      <Component3 />
    </div>)
}

function Component1() {
 render({balance});
}

function Component2() {
 render(<button onClick={exampleFunction}>{balance}</button>);
}
```

Comment: pass it as props to the child components

Answer (score 0):

in your App

```
  <div className="App">
     <Component1 balance={balance}/>
     <Component2 account={account}/>
     <Component3 />
  </div>
```

and in your child component

```
 function Component1(props) {
     render({props.balance});
 }

 function Component2(props) {
     render(<button onClick={exampleFunction}>{props.account}</button>);
  }
```

you can always pass down values.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below approach

```
function App() {
  const [accounts,setAccounts] = useState([]);
  const [balance,setBalance] = useState(0.0);

   useEffect(() =>{
     setBalance(1000);
     loadMetamask();

    const exampleFunction = () => {
      console.log("TEST");
    }
  });

 render(
    <div className="App">
      <Component1 balance={balance}/>
      <Component2 balance={balance} exampleFunction={exampleFunction}/>
      <Component3 accounts={accounts}/>
    </div>)
}

function Component1({balance}) {
 render({balance});
}

function Component2({balance, exampleFunction}) {
 render(<button onClick={exampleFunction}>{balance}</button>);
 }
 
 function Component3({accounts}) {
 render({accounts});
}
```